# Represent levels in a single table or multiple tables

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

If I have a table with multiple optional levels, is it better to have a single table with nullable levels or multiple tables with not nullable levels.

One benefit I could see is the separate tables would permit all keys to be not null which would be better for data integrity.

**SINGLE**  table

```
COUNTRY    BUSINESS   EMPLOYEE   VALUE
-----------------------------------------
1          NULL       NULL       ValueA
1          2          NULL       ValueB
1          2          3          ValueC
```

---

**or**

---

**COUNTRY**  table

```
COUNTRY  VALUE
---------------
1        ValueA
```

**BUSINESS** table

```
COUNTRY    BUSINESS   VALUE
------------------------------
1          2          ValueB
```

**EMPLOYEE** table

```
COUNTRY    BUSINESS   EMPLOYEE  VALUE
-----------------------------------------
1          2          3         ValueC
```

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) PS What's a "level"? You are not explaining what you mean. Although in this particular case it seems like we can guess.

Comment: A level is country (USA), business (Bob's Widgets), employee (Bob)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS You aren't explaining. You have in mind some unexplained notion of a hierarchy or sequence that makes you use 'level' rather than 'entity' or 'category' or 'relationship/association', but you haven't given it. (But anyway it is probably clearer to just not use 'level'.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your business requirement.

Benefits of "multiple tables with not nullable levels" are

- proper indexes
- proper data selection
- proper data manipulation
- Proper use of Constraints
- In single word, **Normalization**

You must look for Normalization and your business requirement before proceeding with the design.

Normalization summary - [Here](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Normalization)

Cheers!!